# Is there a drag-drop/paste image insertion (upload) plugin or similar for TinyMCE?

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

In Gmail it is possible to upload an inline image in the new message/reply window by simply drag-dropping an image from the local file browser (not url) or pasting a copied image into it.

Is there an easy way to add this functionality to a TinyMCE editor? If not, any ideas for how this could be done the best and/or easiest way?

Further info/needs:

- A defined "drop zone" is not usable, as the dropped/pasted image must appear exactly where the user drops/pastes it in the TinyMCE window (i.e. between two paragraphs of text).
- Processeing/resizing the image on or after upload to i.e. max. 500kb would be preferable.
- For the same reason as above - and for easy-of-use reasons - the user should be shown no dialogs, just like Gmail just begins uploading the image, no questions asked.
- Any images dropped/pasted to TinyMCE are to be stored with Amazon Simple Storage Service  (S3). Text from Tiny will be stored in our database. Storing the pasted image(s) in the database instead of Amazon S3 could be an option (using Heroku with PostgreSQL).
- The text and image(s) - in correct order/context - shall be presented to the user again at a later timer, so when dropping/pasting the image, or when saving the TinyMCE form, a placeholder or similar with the image info must be written to TinyMCE so we know which image and where in the text to display when we need to retrieve it sometime in the future.
- Website is using Rails 3.1.3, soon to be upgraded to 3.2.
- HTML5 only is fine, i.e. HTML4 compatability is not important.

Thank you so much! :-)

PS. I have googled + looked at similar questions here at SO without finding the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used plupload quite a bit and found it to be very useful, works well for html4 which was a requirement when the browsers don't have flash or silverlight or html5. Have you looked at that yet? I remember seeing [this](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=133) about Amazon and S3. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much :-)  I'll have a look at that and see if it's usable.

Comment: Did you both have any success with plupload in conjunction with tinymce? Were you able to allow drag-and-drop images into the tinymce, then upload and store those images/files?

Comment: Hi Manachi, nope I've never tried using those two in conjunction, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You may try **[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)** which has got drag & drop support.

Also you may go though (or adapt one from) [**25+ jQuery Drag and Drop Plugins**](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/04/jquery-drag-drop-plugins.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? else let me know.

Comment: Thanks, @blasteralfred. I'd like it to be something that works out of the box, i.e. a plugin, for TinyMCE. Also, the jQuery File Uplaod does upload the file with a thumbnail but I want to show the full image, right there in the TinyMCE editor (just like when you drag-drop an image to the mailbody window in Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is kind of strange. Even the editors uses the trick to encode using base64:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQ..
```

which I guess is OK but with 4-5 photos of reasonable size viewing the post caused the server loads to jump to insane levels.. http taking 100% etc .. it shut us down if more than one or two folk were viewing the post. The funny thing is that they show up fine in the editor -- it's when you save and publish when the pain hits. Not really sure why this hit apache so hard displaying the post (when in the editor it looked fine)

Comment: Is this answer for my question or another one? You're mentioning a "post" - something I have not mentioned :)

Comment: He's referring to what happens when you click save/submit after dragging and dropping an image into TinyMCE.  It "posts" the images as base64 encoded data uri's to the server, where you then have to handle it somehow.